# how to parse optional values from json in android

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have made an android application,In that i want to parse some data from the api,I have some optional values in that api,Sample is as below:
**JSON**

```
{
status: "success",
product_category: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
product: [
{
name: "3SC1G",
id: "128",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372498306.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1400929422.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
product_options: [
{
option_name: "Color",
option_value: "White"
},
{
option_name: "Height",
option_value: "130 cm"
}
]
},
{
name: "3S14FG",
id: "127",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372497779.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1400929548.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "3S13FG",
id: "126",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372496302.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176927.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "3S12MG",
id: "125",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372496174.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176821.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "3S3FG",
id: "124",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372306217.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176740.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "3S9FG",
id: "123",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372305991.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176646.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "3S5MG",
id: "117",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372304662.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176538.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "3S8MG",
id: "116",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372304573.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176461.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "3S10MG",
id: "115",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372304511.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176396.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "M12G",
id: "99",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368463047.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401180875.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "M10G",
id: "98",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368462841.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401180931.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "M8G",
id: "97",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368462735.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401180955.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "M5G",
id: "96",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368462593.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181016.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "M1G",
id: "95",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368452614.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401180978.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "F13GB",
id: "93",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368451347.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181053.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "F9GB",
id: "92",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368450963.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181078.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "F3GB",
id: "91",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368450873.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181131.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
},
{
name: "C1G",
id: "90",
thumb_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368450534.jpg",
big_image: "http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181181.jpg",
product_subcategory: {
name: "Glossy Mannequins",
id: "28"
},
msg_option: "not_available"
}
]
}
```

Inthe above JSON i want to parse the values of "product options"...which is not in all the objects,I have tried "optJSONArray" but not getting solution ,I have tried as below,Which is not working,Please help me to solve this..
**main.jaa**

```
try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    if (jsonObj.has("product")) {

                        subCategories = jsonObj.getJSONArray("product");
                        if (subCategories != null
                                && subCategories.length() != 0) {

                            // looping through All Contacts

                            for (int i = 0; i < subCategories.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject c = subCategories.getJSONObject(i);

                                sub_id = c.getString("id");
                                sub_name = c.getString("name");

                                thumb_image = c.getString("thumb_image");
                                big_image = c.getString("big_image");
                                resultArray.add(big_image);

                                if (c.has("product_options")) {
                                    JSONArray product_optionsarray = c
                                            .optJSONArray("product_options");

                                    for (int j = 0; j < product_optionsarray
                                            .length(); j++) {

                                        JSONObject c1 = product_optionsarray
                                                .optJSONObject(j);

                                        if (c1.has("option_name"))
                                            option_name = c1
                                                    .optString("option_name");
                                        System.out
                                                .println("::::::::::::::::Option name::::::"
                                                        + option_name);

                                        if (c1.has("option_value"))
                                            option_value = c1
                                                    .optString("option_value");
                                        System.out
                                                .println("::::::::::::::::Optionvalue::::::"
                                                        + option_value);
                                    }
                                }
                                HashMap<String, String> subCategory = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                subCategory.put(Const.TAG_CATEGORY_ID, sub_id);
                                subCategory.put(Const.TAG_CATAEGORY_NAME,
                                        sub_name);
                                subCategory.put(Const.TAG_THUMB_IMG,
                                        thumb_image);
                                subCategory.put(Const.TAG_BIG_IMG, big_image);
                                subCategory.put(Const.TAG_OPTION_NAME,
                                        option_name);
                                subCategory.put(Const.TAG_OPTION_VALUE,
                                        option_value);

                                subCatList.add(subCategory);

                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @MilanMaharjan-not getting any error,but not got values...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

        String jsonStr = "{status:\"success\",product_category:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},product:[{name:\"3SC1G\",id:\"128\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372498306.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1400929422.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},product_options:[{option_name:\"Color\",option_value:\"White\"},{option_name:\"Height\",option_value:\"130 cm\"}]},{name:\"3S14FG\",id:\"127\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372497779.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1400929548.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"3S13FG\",id:\"126\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372496302.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176927.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"3S12MG\",id:\"125\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372496174.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176821.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"3S3FG\",id:\"124\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372306217.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176740.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"3S9FG\",id:\"123\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372305991.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176646.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"3S5MG\",id:\"117\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372304662.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176538.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"3S8MG\",id:\"116\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372304573.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176461.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"3S10MG\",id:\"115\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1372304511.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401176396.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"M12G\",id:\"99\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368463047.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401180875.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"M10G\",id:\"98\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368462841.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401180931.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"M8G\",id:\"97\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368462735.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401180955.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"M5G\",id:\"96\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368462593.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181016.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"M1G\",id:\"95\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368452614.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401180978.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"F13GB\",id:\"93\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368451347.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181053.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"F9GB\",id:\"92\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368450963.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181078.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"F3GB\",id:\"91\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368450873.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181131.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"},{name:\"C1G\",id:\"90\",thumb_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/mediumthumb1368450534.jpg\",big_image:\"http://3smannequins.com/uploads/product_image/1401181181.jpg\",product_subcategory:{name:\"Glossy Mannequins\",id:\"28\"},msg_option:\"not_available\"}]}";
        JSONObject jsonObj;
        JSONArray subCategories;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> subCatList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ArrayList<String> resultArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        try{
            if (jsonStr != null && jsonStr.length()>0) {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                if (jsonObj.has("product")) {
                    subCategories = jsonObj.getJSONArray("product");
                    if (subCategories != null && subCategories.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < subCategories.length(); i++) {
                            String sub_id;
                            String sub_name;
                            String thumb_image;
                            String big_image;
                            String option_name="";
                            String option_value="";

                            sub_id = subCategories.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                            sub_name = subCategories.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                            thumb_image = subCategories.getJSONObject(i).getString("thumb_image");
                            big_image = subCategories.getJSONObject(i).getString("big_image");
                            resultArray.add(big_image);

                            if (subCategories.getJSONObject(i).has("product_options")) {
                                JSONArray product_optionsarray = subCategories.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("product_options");
                                for (int j = 0; j < product_optionsarray.length(); j++) {
                                    option_name = product_optionsarray.getJSONObject(j).optString("option_name");
                                    option_value = product_optionsarray.getJSONObject(j).optString("option_value");
                                }
                            }

                            HashMap<String, String> subCategory = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            subCategory.put("ID", sub_id);
                            subCategory.put("NAME",sub_name);
                            subCategory.put("THUMB_IMG",thumb_image);
                            subCategory.put("BIG_IMG", big_image);
                            subCategory.put("OPTION_NAME",option_name);
                            subCategory.put("OPTION_VALUE",option_value);

                            subCatList.add(subCategory);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Size of subCatList : "+subCatList.size());
        System.out.println("Size of resultArray : "+resultArray.size());

        for (HashMap<String,String> row : subCatList){
            System.out.println("ID : "+row.get("ID"));
            System.out.println("NAME : "+row.get("NAME"));
            System.out.println("THUMB_IMG : "+row.get("THUMB_IMG"));
            System.out.println("BIG_IMG : "+row.get("BIG_IMG"));
            System.out.println("OPTION_NAME : "+row.get("OPTION_NAME"));
            System.out.println("OPTION_VALUE : "+row.get("OPTION_VALUE"));
        }
```

Comment: @user3710354,Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

since you already check if jsonOject has "products_options" using if, try removing optJSONArray and just use JSONArray like this:

```
if (c.has("product_options")) {
    JSONArray product_optionsarray = c.JSONArray("product_options");
    // remaining code
```